# I am supposed to get the data that i have set in my servlet in my jsp page

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am supposed to get the data that i have set in my servlet in my jsp page for that i coded the following program but its not working :

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <% public String LoginServlet(HttpServletRequest req) { String n=(String)req.getAttribute("name"); out.println(n); } %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already set the value in the servlet then you can simply print the value by below code in your jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <%=request.getAttribute("name")%>
</body>
</html>
```